# The setting of sudoers file is not reflected

Tags: linux, sudo, nixos

I installed NixOS KDE in the virtual environment of VMware Workstation 14 Pro and I am using it.
I set the user in the /etc/sudoers file, but that setting is not reflected.

*`root` is allowed to do anything.*

```
root ALL = (ALL: ALL) SETENV: ALL
taro ALL = (ALL: ALL) SETENV: ALL ← This setting is not reflected
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: root can anyway do whatever he wants, what's the point ? usually a good question respect 3 steps: 1- Describe the goal, 2- describe the step to reach this goal 3- the problem encounter, feel free to [edit] your question and read the [tour]. also sudo is a service you need to restart it

Comment: Do you mean that `taro` doesn't have the rights of `root`? In order for that to occur, `taro` will need to use `sudo su -` and enter his password again. He won't have have them on his own.

Comment: Is `sudo` itself installed at all?

Comment: $ su -
Password
This problem was solved.
Thank you very much.